# Power bi: Fill cell based on criteria

Tags: powerbi

Hi I have two tables with the following structure:

```
RN  RO
A   X
B   Y
C   Z
D   Y
E   Z
F   X
G   Z
H   Y
I   Z
J   Z
K   Y
L   Y
```

and -

```
RN  Eff Ct  RO
A   1   2   X
B   1   2   Y
C   1   2   Z
D   1   2   Y
E   1   2   Z
F   1   2   X
G   1   2   Z
H   1   22  Y
I   1   2   Z
J   1   2   Z
K   1   22  Y
L   1   2   Y
```

I want to fill RO in table2 based on table1 without establishing any relationship between them.

I tried doing this by making relationship and using `RON = IF('Table2'[RN] = FIRSTNONBLANK(Table1[RN],1), FIRSTNONBLANK(Table1[RO],1),"1")`

I need to remove this relationship any how.
Is their any way to do this without establishing any relationship?

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I used Power Query (Power BI's Query Editor) to do this. I started with this as Table1:

[image]

...and this as Table2:

[image]

Then, working within Table2's query (having selected Table2 in the Queries pane on the left side of the Query Editor's screen), I did the following:

I clicked on the "Add Column" tab and the "Custom Column" button to add a column, and in the Add Custom Column dialog box (see below) I named the new column Table1 and entered the formula `=Table1` to embed a copy of Table1 in each cell of the new column:

[image]

Then I clicked OK to get this:

[image]

Then I clicked on the button at the top of the new column...This one...[image]...to expand the embedded tables. In the dialog that popped up (see below) I kept all default settings as they were. (I specifically wanted the "Use original column name as prefix" selected so it would be clear which RN and RO values came from Table1.)

[image]

Then I clicked OK to get this:

[image]
(actually 144 rows long)

Then I added another column by clicking the "Add Column" tab and "Custom Column" button again. I named the new column MatchedROs and entered the formula `=if [RN]=[Table1.RN] then [Table1.RO] else null` (shown below).

[image]

Then I clicked OK to get this:

[image]
(again, actually 144 rows long)

Then I filtered the MatchedROs column so all rows with null were removed. I clicked the filter button at the top of the MatchedROs column...this one...[image]...and then I deselected the checkbox beside (null) (see below).

[image]

Then I clicked OK to get this:

[image]

At this point, you could remove whichever columns you might prefer removed. *(Keep either Table1.RO or MatchedROs so you have the values from Table1.)*

Here's the final Query Code from the Advanced Editor:

```
let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\MARC_000\Desktop\Criteria..xlsx"), null, true),
Table2_Table = Source{[Item="Table2",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table2_Table,{{"RN", type text}, {"Eff", Int64.Type}, {"Ct", Int64.Type}, {"RO", type text}}),

//The lines above establish Table2 within Power Query, pulling it from the source Excel file and doing initial setup up "stuff".
//The lines that follow are what I did once Table2 was established.

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Table1", each Table1),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Table1", {"RN", "RO"}, {"Table1.RN", "Table1.RO"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table1", "MatchedROs", each if [RN]=[Table1.RN] then [Table1.RO] else null),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each ([MatchedROs] <> null))
in
#"Filtered Rows"
```

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be accomplished using the [`LOOKUPVALUE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492170.aspx) function. In table 2, add a new column with this formula; no relationship required.

```
RO_New = LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[RO], Table1[RN], Table2[RN])
```

[image: New lookup column]